# How to define Euclid's division theorem with quantifiers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Euclid's division theorem states "Letting n be a positive integer, for every integer m there are unique integers
q and r, with 0 ≤ r < n, such that m = nq + r"
And this is how it's written with quantifiers in my book "∀n ≥ 1 ∀m ∃q ∃0 ≤ r < n[m = nq + r]"
The question is why it is "∃q ∃0 ≤ r < n" not "∃!q ∃!0 ≤ r < n"? And also what does uniqueness mean? q and r can't be the same or what?

Comment: I agree  that there should be $!$ for uniqueness. Uniqueness means that there is exactly one pair of $(q,r)$. They can be the same; say $10 = 2*4+2$.

Comment: @AmejiB. thanks for dispelling my doubts